# Mvc 3: displaying viewmodel items in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class like this

```
            public class AmeInvoice
                {
                    public DateTime invoiceDate { get; set; }
                    public string invoiceNumber { get; set; }
                    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
                    public double amount { get; set; }
                    public double amountDue { get; set; }
                }
```

I have a viewmodel like this

```
            public class AmeInvoiceViewModel
                {
                    public List<AmeInvoice> ppInvoices { get; set; }
                    public double otherAmount { get; set; }
                    public double totalDue { get; set; }
                }
```

My action result method in my controller is like this

```
            public actionresult index ()
            {
                ....
                ....
                ....
                List<AmeInvoice> prideInvoices = new List<AmeInvoice>();

                               while (reader.Read())
                               {
                                   prideInvoices.Add(new AmeInvoice()
                                   {
                                      invoiceDate =  Convert.ToDateTime(reader["invoicedate"]),
                                      invoiceNumber = reader["invoicenumber"].ToString(),
                                      accountNumber = reader["account"].ToString(),
                                      amount = Convert.ToDouble(reader["amount"]),
                                      amountDue = Convert.ToDouble(reader["amountdue"])
                                   });

                               }

                var myviewModel = new AmeInvoiceViewModel();
                               myviewModel.ppInvoices = prideInvoices;
                               myviewModel.otherAmount = 20.20;
                               myviewModel.totalDue = 30.20;
                               return View(myviewModel);

            }
```

In my view I have this

```
            @model List<InSCmm.Web.Model.AmeInvoiceViewModel>

            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            }

            <h2>Index</h2>

            <table>

             @foreach (InSCmm.Web.Model.AmeInvoiceViewModel objUser in Model)
             {
               <tr>
                  <td>@objUser.</td>
                  <td>@objUser.</td>
                  <td>@objUser.</td>
                  <td>@objUser.</td>
                  <td>@objUser.</td>
               </tr>
             }
             </table>
```

My questions: I am very new to Mvc and I want to be able to display
the invoiceDate, invoiceNumber, accountNumber, amount, amount due in a table in my view.
At the moment if I do a objUser.  (I don't get these fields)
Please assist. Is this the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view must be strongly typed to the view model that you are passing, not to a list:

```
@model InSCmm.Web.Model.AmeInvoiceViewModel
```

and then:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var objUser in Model.ppInvoices)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@objUser.invoiceDate</td>
            <td>@objUser.invoiceNumber</td>
            <td>@objUser.accountNumber</td>
            <td>@objUser.amount</td>
            <td>@objUser.amountDue</td>
         </tr>
     }
</table>

<div>
    Total due: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.totalDue)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This statement does not work Total due: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.totalDue). I do not have access to totalDue.

Answer (score 2):

Your view is a single entity not an `IEnumerable<AmeInvoiceViewModel>`, so iterating over `Model` (which is a single `AmeInvoiceViewModel`) won't work.

I think you're looking for `Model.ppInvoices`, but then you'll need to iterate over `AmeInvoice` and not `AmeInvoiceViewModel`. something like:

```
<table>
@foreach (AmeInvoice invoice in Model.ppInvoices)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@html.DisplayFor(x => invoice.invoiceDate)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => invoice.invoiceNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => invoice.accountNumber)</td>
        @* ... *@
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: No luck yet. This is what I got.  The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>
(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.